# State of knowledge / research directions academic paper

Tags: architecture, economics

The [SoK paper by Bonneau et al](https://eprint.iacr.org/2015/261) provides a good overview of the state of knowledge (as of 2015) and research directions for Bitcoin. Is there anything similar for Ethereum?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Time to admit that the real purpose of asking this question was to answer it with [my own paper](http://hdl.handle.net/10993/32468).

Answer (score 1):

The knowledge and research is actively developing so there may not be a single academic paper, and you will find similar material on Github:

- https://github.com/ethereum/EIPs/issues (Ethereum Improvement Proposals)
- https://github.com/ethereum/research

Gitter is also active:

- https://gitter.im/ethereum/research
- https://gitter.im/ethereum/EIPs